# regex test tool for waf rule

Tags: google-cloud-armor

I want to know if the [owasp core rule set](https://github.com/coreruleset/coreruleset/tree/v4.0/dev/rules) are the rules that Google Cloud Armor use? If yes how can i test my payloads so it will be compliant to Google [Cloud Armor WAF rules](https://cloud.google.com/armor/docs/waf-rules#crs-3.0)? Any available tools that i can use for testing?

Answer (score 0):

Google Cloud Armor uses various rule sets, including OWASP ModSecurity Core Rule Set (CRS).

If you want to test payloads against CRS, try our sandbox service:
https://coreruleset.org/docs/development/sandbox/